# Как присвоить уникальный класс для UL/LI через PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, css, joomla

Доброе время суток!

Разобравшись с JS, столкнулся с следующей проблемой. Не силен в PHP, не знаю как назначить для каждого пункта UL уникальный свой класс.

```html
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'functions.php';

// Note: it is important to remove spaces between elements.

$tag = ($params->get('tag_id') != NULL) ? ' id="' . $params->get('tag_id') . '"' : '';
if (isset($attribs['name']) && $attribs['name'] == 'user3') {
    $menutype = 'horizontal';

    $start = $params->get('startLevel');

    // check if it is necessary to render subitems:
    $subitems = $GLOBALS['artx_settings']['menu']['show_submenus'] && 1 == $params->get('showAllChildren');
    // true - skip the current node, false - render the current node.
    $skip = false;
    
    echo '<ul class="hmenu"' . $tag . '>';
    foreach ($list as $i => & $item) {
        if ($skip) {
            if ($item->shallower) {
                if (($item->level - $item->level_diff) <= $limit) {
                    echo '</li>' . str_repeat('</ul></li>', $limit - $item->level + $item->level_diff);
                    $skip = false;
                }
            }
            continue;
        }

        $class = 'item-' . $item->id;
        $class .= $item->id == $active_id ? ' current' : '';
        $class .= ('alias' == $item->type
            && in_array($item->params->get('aliasoptions'), $path)
            || in_array($item->id, $path)) ? ' active' : '';
        $class .= $item->deeper ? ' deeper' : '';
        $class .= $item->parent ? ' parent' : '';

        echo '<li class="' . $class . '">';

        // Render the menu item.
        switch ($item->type) {
            case 'separator':
            case 'url':
            case 'component':
                require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_' . $item->type);
                break;
            default:
                require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_url');
                break;
        }
        if ($item->deeper) {
            if (!$subitems) {
                $limit = $item->level;
                $skip = true;
                continue;
            }
            echo '<ul class="dropmenu">';
        }
        elseif ($item->shallower)
            echo '</li>' . str_repeat('</ul></li>', $item->level_diff);
        else
            echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else if (0 === strpos($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'), 'vmenu') || false !== strpos($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'), ' vmenu')) {
    $menutype = 'vertical';

    $start = $params->get('startLevel');

    // check if it is necessary to render subitems:
    $subitems = $GLOBALS['artx_settings']['vmenu']['show_submenus'] && 1 == $params->get('showAllChildren');
    // true - skip the current node, false - render the current node.
    $skip = false;
    // limit of rendering - skip items when a level is exceeding the limit.
    $limit = $start;

    echo '<ul class="vmenu"' . $tag . '>';
    foreach ($list as $i => & $item) {
        if ($skip) {
            if ($item->shallower) {
                if (($item->level - $item->level_diff) <= $limit) {
                    echo '</li>' . str_repeat('</ul></li>', $limit - $item->level + $item->level_diff);
                    $skip = false;
                }
            }
            continue;
        }

        $class = 'item-' . $item->id;
        $class .= $item->id == $active_id ? ' current' : '';
        $class .= ('alias' == $item->type
            && in_array($item->params->get('aliasoptions'), $path)
            || in_array($item->id, $path)) ? ' active' : '';
        $class .= $item->deeper ? ' deeper' : '';
        $class .= $item->parent ? ' parent' : '';

        echo '<li class="' . $class . '">';

        // Render the menu item.
        switch ($item->type) {
            case 'separator':
            case 'url':
            case 'component':
                require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_' . $item->type);
                break;
            default:
                require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_url');
                break;
        }
        if ($item->deeper) {
            if (!$subitems) {
                $limit = $item->level;
                $skip = true;
                continue;
            }
            echo '<ul' . ($subitems && in_array($item->id, $path) ? ' class="dropmenu"' : '') . ' >';
        }
        elseif ($item->shallower)
            echo '</li>' . str_repeat('</ul></li>', $item->level_diff);
        else
            echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    $menutype = 'default';
    echo '<ul class="menu' . $params->get('class_sfx') . '"' . $tag . '>';
    foreach ($list as $i => &$item) {

        $class = 'item-' . $item->id;
        $class .= $item->id == $active_id ? ' current' : '';
        $class .= ('alias' == $item->type
            && in_array($item->params->get('aliasoptions'), $path)
            || in_array($item->id, $path)) ? ' active' : '';
        $class .= $item->deeper ? ' deeper' : '';
        $class .= $item->parent ? ' parent' : '';

        echo '<li class="' . $class . '">';

        // Render the menu item.
        switch ($item->type) {
            case 'separator':
            case 'url':
            case 'component':
                require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_'.$item->type);
                break;
            default:
                require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_url');
                break;
        }

        if ($item->deeper)
            echo '<ul class="dropmenu">';
        elseif ($item->shallower)
            echo '</li>' . str_repeat('</ul></li>', $item->level_diff);
        else
            echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Разобрался лишь в том, что за наименование класса отвечают эти строки

```html
   if ($item->deeper) {
            if (!$subitems) {
                $limit = $item->level;
                $skip = true;
                continue;
            }
            echo '<ul class="dropmenu">';
        }
        elseif ($item->shallower)
            echo '</li>' . str_repeat('</ul></li>', $item->level_diff);
        else
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как к названию класса добавить +1 или текстовое значение, чтобы получилось, dropmenu1, dropmenu2, dropmenu3 и тд.

Пробовал через JS, но скрипт для которого нужны классы все допклассы N+1 считает за один. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для уникальности добавляете текущую дату и время.

```
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
echo '<ul class="dropmenu'.$now->format("YmdHisu").'">';
```

Или просто время

```
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
echo '<ul class="dropmenu'.$now->format("Hisu").'">';
```

Или ещё проще обычное рандомное значение от 0 до 1000 (но может выпасть два одинаковых числа)

```
echo '<ul class="dropmenu'.rand(0,1000).'">';
```

Или в заведите обычный счётчек и в цикле его увеличивайте.

Comment: я думаю речь идет об уникальности только внутри документа - достаточно обычного инкрементного счетчика

Comment: @splash58 там столько всего написано, что мне даже лень цикл выискивать

Comment: А можно как то сделать $i++ где i=1? Попробовал, но записывается не в название класса,  а вот так <ul class="dropmenu hmenu-left-to-right drop1" 1"="" style="">

Comment: @V.Shukhminov значит вы что-то не то заменили в своём коде.

Comment: @V.Shukhminov Заменит ваш `echo '<ul class="dropmenu">';` на один из вариантов. Обратите внимание, что в коде у вас таких конструкций ДВЕ

Comment: Спасибо большое, исходя из ваших ответов, сделал такую конструкцию и все заработало! 

$a = "1";
$dropmenu = "dropmenu";

 echo '<ul class="' .$dropmenu.$a++.'">';